# Why are diffusion models so good compared to other existing generative methods?

Tags: generative-adversarial-network

While variational models, normalizing-flow-based models and adversarial models can all be shown to have a probabilistic theory backing them like diffusion models, except for the computational complexity, diffusion models gradually become the dominant paradigm.

I see in quite a literature we talk about WHETHER diffusion models are better than other models and HOW MUCH by showing the benchmark result, but I couldn't find one talking about what are the characteristic of diffusion methods that enable such a quality leap, i.e., WHY.

For example, in GAN, mode collapse seems to be an inherent problem of the models, but I have not seen a discussion about why other models do not suffer from the same problem from a theoretical standpoint (to my knowledge). (We have discussions about how to alleviate the problem within the adversarial framework, but I want such discussion across different models, in a sort of uniform way)

I am hoping for literature or discussions that can enlighten me, with potentially a list of problems that other models suffer, that diffusion mechanism avoids or solves, not by showing me the benchmark result, but by proving to me (even if it is not a mathematically rigorous proof) that, e.g, such such quantity (variance of some random variables e.g) in a diffusion model is bounded by such such constant while in other models it is unbounded.